# How to create custom build environment in Team services?

Tags: windows, azure, tfs, azure-devops

When I was trying to build some sample node app, its internally having hosted agents which taking care the build process. 
But If I want to create my custom build environment what is the procedure?
Assume for example if I have one windows environment in azure, should I able to use that as my custom build agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the VM to create your custom build environment.

You can configure the VSTS Agent on the VM. In that case, it won't be the hosted queue which has hosted agents, you will have to select the queue in your build definition against which you have configured your azure bm.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent